# UCWA getting a 502 response (Bad Gateway, policy prevents request from being proxied)

Tags: c#, httprequest, skype-for-business, ucwa

I am following the steps to create an application.

I can successfully retrieve the token but when I make a POST httpRequest to '/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications' I am getting the following errors:

The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway
Policy prevents request from being proxied

For the first time I got the status "Ok" but from second time on words I got the above error.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an Skype for Business environment issue. I have see that in some environments as well and the root cause was either an issue with DNS (e.g. Split DNS) or an Reverse Proxy isn´t configured correctly (as mentioned [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/skypeforbusiness/256-resolved-ms-web-application-proxy-used-with-sfb-caused-a-error-502.html)).

However without having more info's from your side its hard to troubleshoot that.

*P.S. You might wish to perform some troubleshooting steps together with your Skype for Business administrator (as mentioned [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/skypeforbusiness/256-resolved-ms-web-application-proxy-used-with-sfb-caused-a-error-502.html).)*